# What features can be extracted from a probability distribution and how does the features change from baseline to different category/cases?

Tags: distributions, descriptive-statistics, goodness-of-fit, feature-engineering

I have been looking online regarding feature extraction and I am looking at extracting features from probability distribution in order to understand the characteristics of the distribution. I know the most common features from distribution are the following:

- Mean
- Variance
- Standard Deviation
- Skewness
- Kurtosis

I used some links to get these features which can be found below:

- [Characteristics of probability distribution](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fslideplayer.com%2Fslide%2F5760162%2F&psig=AOvVaw2C5CHdii24aiTASnodpco4&ust=1617703579416000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAMQjB1qFwoTCMDPyNTt5u8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAK)
- [Characterizing a Distribution](http://work.thaslwanter.at/Stats/html/statsDistributions.html)

For my case, I won't be concentrating on the features that look into the location of the dispersion but the measure of dispersion. So, I know I would eliminate mean from the features, however, I found a book ([Exploratory and Multivariate Data](https://www.elsevier.com/books/exploratory-and-multivariate-data-analysis/jambu/978-0-08-092367-3)) where I found the following features that concentrate on dispersion:

- Range
- Interquartile Range
- Variance
- Standard Deviation
- Median Deviation
- Geometric Deviation
- Absolute and Relative Dispersion: Coefficient of Variation

I have been wondering if there are other types of features that explain the characteristic of a probability distribution and if the features that I mentioned above are correct? Furthermore, say I have different cases and baseline, is there a way to measure how does a feature change from baseline to different cases and how sensitive it is? What came to my head is a method called Percentage Change and can be done using the equation:

[image]

Where,

- *C* is the percentage change
- *x1* is the initial value
- *x2* is the new value(value from a specific case)

*Side question:*

- Regarding the Goodness-of-fit tests, I know that they are used to
  find a suitable distribution that fits the dataset that you are
  using. I want to know if there is a link or article that looks into
  the type of tests and if there were a review on them and what could
  be the better goodness of fit test to use to get the distribution for
  given dataset?

Comment: Could you give us more context on what is your data and why do you want to "extract features" from it? Why not take the distributions as-is?

Comment: @Tim See edited question